# How can I reduce the cost of triggering a lambda synchronously?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My lambda needs to call another lambda synchronously since it needs to get the response value. I know that it is an anti-pattern since it double the execution time. Is there a way to improve that? I still need to use the two lambdas because the other lambda is written in a different language which can't be compiled into one lambda. I have searched step function but it doesn't seem it provides any solution.

I control the two lambdas but they have to be written in different languages, one is node, the other is .Net.

The use case is lambdaA is sitting behind API gateway. It triggers lambdaB to get some response. Then lambdaA applies some logic based on the response from lambdaB. Finally response it to clients.

So it is a request-response mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to call one lambda from the other one, and can't de-couple them using SQS, SNS or SFs, then sadly there is **not much that can be done** to reduce the execution time. You will be paying for the time the first function waits for the completion of the second one.

The effects of this mostly depending on the **execution time** of the second lambda function (seconds or minutes?). If its just few seconds, then probably re-designing your architecture to de-couple the functions is not worth the time and effort. But if the second function requires, lets say 10 minutes, then the situation changes.

In that case, de-coupling is usually done through **SNS, SQS or SFs**. But without exact details of your use-case, e.g., can you modify the two functions at will?, its difficult to provide more details. But then, if you can modify them to your liking, maybe you can re-write them into one function?

Comment: I can modify them but have to be in different lanuages, one is nodejs the other is .Net. It seems I can't decouple them by using SQS, SNS etc, because the use case is users send request to API gateway which triggers the first lambda, first labmda triggers the second lambda to get the response, then apply some logic based on the response and finally send back to users.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao I see. If the users wait for the results of their requests, then I don't see how you could de-couple them unfortunately. The users would also have to invoke your api asynchronously, and then use different request to get the results if the functions were de-coupled.